# Hibernate: Createsqlquery.. error in getting some columns for my entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

In hibernate I'm coding a search form win Swing.
For that purpose:

1. I have my entity A with 10 fields, but in the case of this searching just I need, of the same entity, only 5 fields/columns.
2. I wanna use SQL native query:

`SELECT cli.field1, cli.field2, cli.field3, cli.field4 cli.field5 FROM sells.customers` 
...query in PostgreSQL

3. But when I add:

`.addEntity(Entity.class)`

4. Hibernate throws exception that could not find the rest of columns. Obviusly if only I put `SELECT * from sells.customers` that error doesn't appear. But i must do a sql query for performance.

Question: How can I tell hibernate -in SQL native query- to only return those five columns or fields, but using the same entity preivously mentioned.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your tips...
Fortunatelly I did some changes:

1. The entity is the same.
2. Delete the `.addEntity(...)` and replace it with:

   `SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlquery);`
3. And the next line is:

   `return query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(entityClass)).list();`

With this line I'm forcing to return items with `entityClass` type, no matter if I only selected five columns. Each line of the list will have an `entityClass` object with just five attributes with data extracted. The rest of the attributes -not selected in the main query- are null.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this, provided you create additional constructor to your entity, but with those few fields only - so assuming you would want to e.g. query only first name and last name from `Person` table, it would look like this:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Your query could then be similar to this:

```
SELECT new Person(p.firstName, p.lastName) FROM Person p WHERE p.lastName = :lastName
```

More examples can be found directly in [Hibernate tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)